# Custom fields in my joomla component

Tags: joomla

I add in submenu of my component for Joomla 3.8 next items:

```
JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(JText::_('JGLOBAL_FIELDS'), 'index.php?option=com_fields&context=com_railway2.direction', $vName == 'fields.fields');
JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(JText::_('JGLOBAL_FIELD_GROUPS'), 'index.php?option=com_fields&view=groups&context=com_railway2.direction', $vName == 'fields.groups');
```

And made 1 custom group and 1 custom field.

How i start to add values in this custom field in my view "direction"?